# add column with fixed values for each value of another column Redshift

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift, multiple-columns

I have following table

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD96k.png)

want to add date range  for each user

[image]

How to achieve this:

1. if this is possible from query in Redshift then that be useful
2. If not, efficient way to create this in python pandas as data is having 8lk records

Comment: this is a Cartesian product, pretty simple to do both in python & sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this dataframe `df`:

```
   userid username
0       1        a
1       2        b
2       3        c
```

you can use numpy [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
dr = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-03')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.to_numpy(), len(dr), 0), columns=df.columns).assign(date=np.tile(dr.to_numpy(), len(df)))
```

Result:

```
  userid username       date
0      1        a 2020-01-01
1      1        a 2020-01-02
2      1        a 2020-01-03
3      2        b 2020-01-01
4      2        b 2020-01-02
5      2        b 2020-01-03
6      3        c 2020-01-01
7      3        c 2020-01-02
8      3        c 2020-01-03
```

Comment: try using merge create a dataframe from dr and assign a dummy column `pd.merge(df.assign(key='var1'),dr.assign(key='var1'),on='key').drop('key',1)`

Comment: @Datanovice: this works too and is a nice solution, but even for the toy data `merge` if 5 times slower than the numpy solution (OP asked for an *efficient* way)

Comment: @Stef numpy is best, it took few secs to execute over 8lk records. Thank you.Datanovice your solution works too but taking too much time because of merge. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Sql this is simple too - just cross join with the list of dates you want to add to each row (replicate rows).  You can see that in your example that 3 rows and 3 dates results in 9 rows.  (untested explanatory code:)

```
select userid, username, "date" from <table> cross join (select values ('2020-01-01'::date), ('2020-02-01'::date), ('2020-03-01'::date));
```

Now the problem with simple approach is that if you are dealing with large tables and long lists of dates the multiplication will kill you.  10 billion rows by 5,000 dates is 15 trillion resulting rows - making this will take a long time and storing it will takes lots of disk space.  For small tables and short lists of dates this works fine.

If you are in the "big" side of things you will likely need to rethink what you are trying to do.  Since you are using Redshift there is a possibility that you may need to do this.